# Exclude entire QuerySet from results

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
 class LibraryEntry(models.Model):
   player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
   player_lib_song_id = models.IntegerField()
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   artist = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   album = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   track = models.IntegerField()
   genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   duration = models.IntegerField()
   is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   class Meta:
     unique_together = ("player", "player_lib_song_id")

   def __unicode__(self):
     return "Library Entry " + str(self.player_lib_song_id) + ": " + self.title

 class BannedSong(models.Model):
   lib_entry = models.ForeignKey(LibraryEntry)

   def __unicode__(self):
     return "Banned Library Entry " + str(self.lib_entry.title)
```

I'd like to do a query like this:

```
 banned_songs = BannedSong.objects.filter(lib_entry__player=activePlayer)
 available_songs = LibraryEntry.objects.filter(player=activePlayer).exclude(banned_songs)
```

Basically if a song is banned, I want to exclude it from my set of available songs. Is there a way to do this in Django?

Comment: Can you not make 'is_banned' a boolean field of your LibraryEntry model?

Comment: Yes, but very few songs will actually be banned compared to the number that aren't. I figured adding a boolean field that for the most part is only going to be one value is bad form.

Comment: I wouldn't say so, but I suppose it's a matter of taste.

Comment: I don't see why `BannedSong` has a `ForeignKey` -- shouldn't it be a `OneToOneField` if you really want `BannedSong` to be a separate model (which it shouldn't be)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
banned_song_ids = (BannedSong.objects.filter(lib_entry__player=activePlayer)
                                            .values_list('lib_entry', flat=True))

available_songs = (LibraryEntry.objects.filter(player=activePlayer)
                                            .exclude('id__in' = banned_song_ids))
```

The alternative is:

```
available_songs = (LibraryEntry.objects.filter(player=activePlayer)
                                          .filter(bannedsong__isnull = True))
```

Comment: I tried this before actually and it doesn't work. Django compares the id field of each set. I want it to compare the id field of the LibraryEntry set with the lib_id field of the banned_songs set. Not compare id to id.

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum I wrote that before I realized `banned_songs` was a queryset from a different model, rather than the same model. I updated it to use a `values_list`.

Comment: Awesome. That should work pretty well actually. Though I'm afraid of some performance issues in the case of banned_songs being large. But like I said, I don't anticipate it being large. If I make it a OneToOneField instead of a foreign key, does that change things?

Comment: The bannedsong__isnull works! Exactly what I wanted. Awesome and thanks!