# Django excluding one queryset from another

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following two models:

```
class DeliveryTime(models.Model):
   delivery_time = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class BlockedDeliveryTime(models.Model):
   delivery_date = models.DateField()
   delivery_time = models.ForeignKey(DeliveryTime)
```

I want to return all the available delivery times for a day i.e. all `DeliveryTime` excluding the `BlockedDeliveryTime`.

```
 blocked_delivery_times = BlockedDeliveryTime.objects.filter(delivery_date=delivery_date)
 delivery_times = DeliveryTime.objects.all()
```

From `delivery_times` queryset I want to remove all `blocked_delivery_times.delivery_time`

How can I do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude entire QuerySet from results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182945/exclude-entire-queryset-from-results)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
blocked_delivery_times = BlockedDeliveryTime.objects.filter(delivery_date=delivery_date) \
    .values('delivery‌​_time')
delivery_times = DeliveryTime.objects.exclude(id__in=blocked_delivery_times)
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, but the exclude is not working `delivery_times = DeliveryTime.objects.exclude(delivery_time__in=t)` is returning all DeliveryTime

Comment: @reevh, I had a typo: `delivery_times__in`. See the corrected answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I noticed that typo before my first comment. If you look at my first comment you can see it was fixed. Is there any thing you can think of that could cause this problem?

Comment: does exclude take list? `exclude(delivery_time__in=t)` where `t` is a list

Comment: Got it working, i followed your idea but changed code to the following: `blocked_delivery_times = BlockedDeliveryTime.objects.filter(delivery_date=delivery_date).values('delivery_time')       
        delivery_times = DeliveryTime.objects.exclude(id__in=blocked_delivery_times)`. If you can update your answer with the above code i can accept it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 12):

With the release of Django 1.11 you can use [`difference`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#difference), which takes advantage of the `EXCEPT` SQL operator. I think it might be more efficient because you aren't evaluating a query to get a list of values.

Answer (score 7):

For newer version of Django (I use 1.10) you should not use .objects for the second line.

```
blocked_delivery_times = BlockedDeliveryTime.objects.filter(delivery_date=delivery_date) \
    .values('delivery‌​_time')
delivery_times = DeliveryTime.exclude(id__in=blocked_delivery_times)
```

Comment: Why should one not use .objects for the second line?

Comment: It's just a change they made on newer versions of django

Comment: I don't think this is accurate